# How to write GStreamer plugin that use overlaycomposition?

Tags: c, plugins, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I would like to learn how to transform [overlaycomposition.c](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/main/subprojects/gst-plugins-base/tests/examples/overlaycomposition/overlaycomposition.c) into a plugins element.

The objective is to use it with `gst-launch` like

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! my_overlay_plugin ! autovideosink
```

I've start a plugin using GstBaseTransform template and I wonder if it's possible to subclass `GstVideoOverlayComposition` ?

I don't know how to bind `draw` and `caps-changed` ?

Do you know if some source code are available to learn ?